# Sufficient Method for Testing Equality

Tags: java

I want to implement a custom `equals()` method for a class I have, `Board`. The method compares the arrays of each board, defined as `private int[] board`, returning true if the arrays are equal and false if they are not. I know there are some "gotchas" in testing equality, so I was wondering if the following code was optimal and sufficient for truly testing the equality:

```
public boolean equals(Object y) {
    if (this.getClass() != y.getClass()) return false; //must be same class -- duh
    Board that = (Board) y; //y cast as Board
    int[] thisBoardCopy = this.getBoard(); //copy of current board
    int[] thatBoardCopy = that.getBoard(); //copy of y's board
    return Arrays.equals(thisBoardCopy, thatBoardCopy);
}
```

Comment: You forgot a null check at the start. if y is null this will break

Answer (score 2):

The usual idiom for writing `.equals` methods in java is this:

```
public boolean equals(Object y) {
    if(y == this) return true;
    if(!(y instanceof Board.class)) return false;
    final Board that = (Board) y; //y cast as Board
    return Arrays.equals(getBoard(), that.getBoard());
}
```

The first test just speeds things up if it's the same `Board`, the second test has two functions:

1. It returns `false` if `y` is `null` - this reduces the amount of code a bit
2. It does your check that `y` is of the right class.

**EDIT**

I'm not sure what you mean by "copy" in your comments, I assume you mean "reference". If you are copying those arrays before passing them into the `equals` I would suggest that you don't as this method can be called many many (many) times if this object finds its way into a `Map` or `Set`.

Answer (score 0):

You better do

```
if (!this.getClass().equals (y.getClass())) return false;
```

otherwise there will be NullPointerException in case `y` is `null`.

No.  This still throws NPE.  Should be:

```
if (y == null || !this.getClass().equals (y.getClass())) return false;
```

Comment: use the `instanceof` operator - this returns false if the comparator is `null`, `if(!(Y instanceof MyClass.class)) return false;`

Comment: @bmorris591 `instanceof` has different meaning and is slower, though in many cases `instanceof` is better.

Comment: @MikhailVladimirov please correct your answer, even after the edit the first part is simply wrong.

Comment: and you can compare classes with ==, the equals was only there for your first concern, which as you yourself noticed was misplaced.